# How to calculate remaining hours to setted time

Tags: java, android, timer, alarm

I want to create an Alarm like app in Android(Java), I want to caluclate how to many hours and minutes left. When I set my alarm to 1:00 am. My current time is 20:00 pm, it will show me "Alarm will sound after 5 hours", but it shows me after 19 hours, how to solve it.

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Hours: " + (calendar.getTime().getHours() - timePicker.getCurrentHour()) + "Minutes: " + (calendar.getTime().getMinutes() - timePicker.getCurrentMinute()) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: please share the code where you are calculating the time difference?

Comment: I have added code

Comment: To answer your question - you are not accounting for alarm time in future - you are subtracting now (10pm (or 2000 hours)) - 1AM (or 0100) hours  - which is 19 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    int hrs = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

    Calendar alCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    alCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());

    alCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

    if(timePicker.getCurrentHour() < hrs){
        alCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }

    long diff = alCal.getTimeInMillis() - cal.getTimeInMillis();

    long leftHrs = (diff / (60 * 60 * 1000));
    long leftMin = (diff / (60 * 1000)) - (leftHrs * 60);

    // Output
    Toast.makeText(this,"Hours: "+leftHrs+"Minutes: "+leftMin,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Now 4:00 pm and a I set time to 1:00 am it give me "Hours: -14" and "Minutes: -899", It should give me 8 hours not -14 hours, how to solve it ?

Comment: @MovsesMartirosyan, what was the date that you had selected? And can you also share the currentHr and minute value that timepicker is returning along with day returned by datepicker. Also, I have updated the logic for minutes calculation slightly, so please have a look

Comment: I dont select date, I only select Hour and Minute from time picker, for example I select 01:00 am, and I want to calculate how many hours and minutes left from now to 01:00 am.

Comment: So, alarm time is set only for the next day always?

Comment: See, now 16:00 pm, I set time with timepicker to for example 18:00 pm, It gives Hours left 2. It is correct,  but when I set to 3:00 am it gives me (3-16= -13) hours instead of giving Hours left 7(from 16:00 pm to 3:00 am)

Comment: @MovsesMartirosyan, please have a look at my updated answer and let me know if it solves the problem.

Comment: @MovsesMartirosyan Happy to help. Please upvote my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use Java Date.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance().set(...); //set the date
Date alarmDate = cal.time;

long duration = alarmDate - System.currentTimeMillis();
int hours = duration / (1000 * 60 * 60);
```

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

Comment: Android does not support those classes in APIs < 28 I think (LocalTime/LocalDate)...

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android (<26) in [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

Modern solution uses the *java.time* classes.

Get current moment on your default time zone. If important, confirm with the user.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Extract the time-of-day.

```
LocalTime lt = zdt.toLocalTime() ;
```

If after the alarm time, add a day.

```
LocalTime alarm = LocalTime.of( 1 , 0 ) ;

LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
if( ! alarm.isBefore( lt ) ) {
    ld = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;
}

ZonedDateTime fire = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , alarm , z )
```

If your other code needs UTC, extract `Instant`

```
Instant instant = fire.toInstant() ;
```

Calculate elapsed time.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdt , fire ) ; 
int hours = d.toHoursPart() ;
int minutes = d.toMinutesPart() ;
```

You should add a bit more code, a fudge factor, in case the current moment is extremely close to the alarm time, close enough that it might roll over the alarm time as this code executes.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: What does the code do ?  How can I get remaining hours and minutes ? My API level is 19